# FastDTW for Hand Gesture Pattern Recognition Example

Tags: java, machine-learning, accelerometer, pattern-recognition, tilt-sensor

I am using a tri-axis accelerometer to capture the movements of the hand. While coming through the existing solutions, I found that FastDTW is a suitable one for identifying the patterns of a time series data set. I came across the following libraries.

https://code.google.com/p/fastdtw/
https://github.com/cscotta/fastdtw/tree/9322f2a74c96f9c38f253c702a57dd23a16cf777

I'm new to this and I want to know, whether there are any useful examples that i could use to start playing with that. What i want to do is to give the Accelerometer singals as input and identify the pattern so that it would represent a particular movement. 
I would highly appreciate if you could provide some useful code example for this.

Thank You.

Comment: have you gain any new information in this topis, which you could add to your question ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, the DTW algorithm should work, however getting consistent readings is the hard part.